# Set a background for my page in React

Tags: reactjs

I have been working on a simple application and i am trying to set an images a back-ground for my main page (the image cover all my background ) i have checked many answers that are on stackoverflow but i could not it correct, i wonder how to fix that ?

[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKk2M.png)

```
    App {
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      background: url("N.png") no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .App-logo {
      animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
      height: 80px;
    }

    .App-header {
      background-color: #222;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 20px;
      color: white;
    }

    .App-title {
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .App-intro {
      font-size: large;
    }

    @keyframes App-logo-spin {
      from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `height` of the parent elements to `100%` also.

```
html,
body,
#root {
    height: 100%;
}
```